# OpenCV with AWS DLAMI

Tags: python, opencv, amazon-ec2, gpu

Suppose I have access to an AWS **p3.2xlarge** instance **(TeslaV100 GPU)** with  **Deep Learning AMI (Amazon Linux 2) Version 58.0** installed. I'm trying to learn GPU programming, how to deal with CUDA & all of that jazz but feeling quite lost...

Now what I have to do is a simple task with OpenCV (python). What sort of changes I should apply to my code given it runs well on a sample on my machine.

Here is the code :

```py
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

sift= cv2.SIFT_create()

def get_sift_descriptors(img_dir):
  images = os.listdir(img_dir)
  for image_file in tqdm(images):
    i = cv2.imread(img_dir+ image_file)
    id = get_image_id(image_file) #imported from a custom module
    
    KP, D = sift.detectAndCompute(i, None)
    np.savetxt('{}.txt'.format(id), D)

dir = 'path_to_images'
get_sift_descriptors(dir)
```

Are there any modifications I need to make to run this effectively on the GPU of my instance? Any help would be really appreciated. I know it should be easy, it is just my first time to run anything on a GPU on such a scale so it is a little bit confusing.

Comment: unfortunately, there is neither CUDA nor OCL code for SIFT (it only runs on the CPU). also, you have to build your own cv2 with CUDA sdk, to use that.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there an alternative that you know?

Comment: SURF instead of SIFT, maybe. but again, you have to build your own (with OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON, to use it. you also could try ORB with cv2.UMat, to use OCL (without modding your cv2, that's builtin)